# JavaScript - Results Displaying in IE but not Chrome or FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, i'm new to Javascript, let's get that out of the way.

Anyway, I have the following code that works in IE, but not in Chrome or FF. It's supposed to grab the data from the Reddit RSS, then just output it, that's it. It only is working in IE. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<html>                                                                  
<head>                                                                  
<script type="text/javascript"         
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript"> 


var result = null;
 $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.reddit.com/.rss",
    type: 'get',
   dataType: 'html',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
     result = data;

    }
 });

 document.write(result);

</script>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is not properly formed. You have a closing head tag inside of your closing body tag.

Answer (score 2):

yes, this code doesn't look right. it's a race condition. document.write executes immediately. the ajax may or may not have set the result in time. you need to add the result to the page in the success event...something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.reddit.com/.rss",
    type: 'get',    dataType: 'html',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
     $("#some-div").html(data);

    }  });
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to recommend leaving async as true? It shouldn't matter how long it takes to grab the RSS feed; once it arrives, shove it into the div and keep on trucking in the meantime.

Comment: yeah, I just copied his code. he probably had that in there due to the racing so it would execute inline or something. I'm just concerned with the success function.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah, I don't know why but I didn't look at the original code until AFTER my comment, so I was looking at the ajax call on its own and didn't think there was a race condition in the first place (even though you said it!). You'd certainly have to do something different like render the empty page and THEN do the Ajax call on document ready for async to be false.

Comment: Still am not getting results with the write in the success function, does it actually work for you guys? I'm at work currently, which obviously does have some security in place --- not sure if that would effect it thoug

Comment: I think one of the problems you might be running into is cross site security...calling another domain via ajax...

Comment: It works for me in IE as well, as does my original. THe thing is though its an XML feed thats public, so you theoretically should be able to call / access it right?

Comment: yeah, I think you are running up against browser security...in chrome I got this error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.reddit.com/.rss. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: there are ways around that...like call a method on your server and pass the feed through from there.

Comment: @Timmerz I was thinking of doing that...routing it to my own hosted server; but the ultimate goal here is to make a chrome extension that others could use -- i'd rather not have all the traffic routed through my host. Unless you meant something different?

Comment: oh, okay...it looks like you can request permission in the extension to that site:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html and here: 
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/faq.html#faq-dev-02

Answer (score 0):

You have race condition due to `$.ajax` being asynchronous. Display the result in the success handler instead, so that the request is guaranteed to have finished.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.reddit.com/.rss",
    type: 'get',
   dataType: 'html',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      document.write(data);
    }
 });
```

**Update**

Since you set async to false, the above statement isn't applicable. However, I haven't ever found a good reason to use `document.write()`, which might be part of your issue. Try using another method to inject the data into your page such as `.html()`, `.append()`, `alert()`, etc. And it wouldn't hurt to do this inside `document.ready` either.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var result = null;
     $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.reddit.com/.rss",
        type: 'get',
       dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
         result = data;
        }
     });

    alert(result);
    $("body").append(result);
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure using document.write after the page load will have some very unintended consequences...point taken though. you beat me! :-)

Comment: That's not exactly true, async false should calse the success callback to run before the call to `$.ajax` finishes. `document.write` in the success handler is going to wipe away the entire page for sure

Comment: He does have the async flag set to false, here. The problem here is actual a subtle difference in how the three Javascript engines are executing the ``success`` callback. (And this could be caused by code that checks whether or not it's running in IE.) Basically, it appears that the IE code is all running inside of a single event in the event loop, while Firefox and Chrome have at least two events -- I'm unsure whether the "split" is on calling the ``success`` callback, or the initial ``$.ajax`` function, though.

Comment: Still am not getting results with the write in the success function, does it actually work for you guys? I'm at work currently, which obviously does have some security in place --- not sure if that would effect it though.

Comment: @user988921 Any reason you are doing this synchronously?

Comment: @jrummell i've used it both ways, neither will work in FF or Chrome :/

Answer (score 0):

What about processing in this manner:

```
(function(url, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            callback(data.responseData.feed);
        }
    });
})('http://www.reddit.com/.rss', function(feed) {
    var entries = feed.entries,
        feedList = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        feedList += '<li><a href="' + entries[i].link + '">' + entries[i].title + '</a></li>';
    }
    jQuery('.rssfeed > ul').append(feedList);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="rssfeed">
    <h4>RSS News</h4> 
    <ul></ul> 
</div>
```

sample: http://jsfiddle.net/QusQC/

Comment: Note, if you update your jQuery version, you can process XML better as-is.